# How to search by related model field using django-extra-views?

Tags: django, django-views

I got `Person` object with foreign key to `contact` model. Contact has first_name field.
Howe do I search by that first_name field?
models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    (...)
    contact = models.ForeignKey('addressbook.Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    (...)

class Contact(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField("Nazwisko", max_length="40", blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField("Imię", max_length="40", blank=False) 
    (...)
```

view:

```
class personListPlus(SortableListMixin, SearchableListMixin, ListView):
    model = Person
    search_fields = ['contact__first_name','contact__last_name']
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = 'list_plus.html'
    sort_fields = ['contact__first_name', 'contact__last_name'                 ]
```

Sorting works just fine but I'm no sure how to create GET search request.
I tried `http://{VIEW_URL}?q=contact__first_name=ADAM`
but in response I got : `Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried escaping `=` sign in url by `%3D` but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of django have a security feature which prevents lookups on related models.
The workaround can be found on this question:
[Django: Filtering by %filter% not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441084/django-filtering-by-filter-not-allowed)

Comment: That means i have to put `lookup_allowed` method in my  view, correct?

Comment: As i see in django changelog `lookup_allowed` is method of `ModelAdmin` and I'm not using it here. I use `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify which of the fields will be searched in the query parameter of the URL. Your URL should look like this:

`http://{VIEW_URL}?q=ADAM`

This will search in both **contact__first_name** and **contact__last_name** fields, since those are the fields specified by the *search_field* attribute of your view.

You can have a look at the **get_queryset** method of the [SearchableListMixin](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/blob/master/extra_views/contrib/mixins.py) class to see how the query is parsed and of the class handles both the query parameter and the search fields.

Comment: same error `Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains`