# Django admin filtering users

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an app which is like a `store` where each store has many `products` and a product has many `orders` (`product_id`, `user_id`). On the products page I show the number of users that own that product and I want to place a link that will redirect me to the list for those users.

I create the link as follows:

```
def users_link( self, product ):
    url = urlresolvers.reverse( 'admin:auth_user_changelist' )
    return u'<a href="%s?orders__product_id=%d">%s</a>' %( url, product.pk, product.users_count )
```

But I get the following error:

```
DisallowedModelAdminLookup at /admin/auth/user/
Filtering by orders__product_id__exact not allowed
```

Even if I add `orders__product_id` to the list of allowed `list_filter` for users it still denies me. I can see the filter on the users page but when I click on it it just errors out. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468224/432849.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you don't register this filter with the `UserAdmin` model.
To add a filter to the `Users` section in the admin panel you could add it to existing `UserAdmin` model in the **admin.py** file of your app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```

then add the filter you want

```
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('orders__product_id',)
```

You should see now in the `User` section of the admin panel, in the right sidebar, a new filter. If the filter is incorrect you should see the error in the shell.